# truncate on collections with many indexes very slow

Tags: arangodb

I use a collection with about 2 Mio small records and more than 15 indexes. Sometimes I have to emtpy it. I thought the fastest way would be to simply truncate it. But this takes hours.
When I manually delete all the indexes before, it is only a matter of seconds. But then each time, I have to recreate the indexes again afterwards.

What makes the difference of truncate with/without indexes? And is this necessary, as far as I unserstand, truncate means: "throw everything away (also the full indexes)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `truncate` command is by itself a transactional operation. 
If it fails somewhere in the middle, it can recover and restore the already deleted documents. Therefore it is about the same as looping over all documents in a collection and removing them one-by-one.

Possibly it makes sense to have a short-cut version of `truncate`, which just removes all data in the collection without any chance to restore the documents. Of course such `truncate` couldn't be made part of another transaction. But if the choice is left to the user, that would be ok I think.

Comment: Souns good. and especially whenever I press the truncate button in the web UI it is ensured that this is not part of a more complex transaction, I guess.